# How to replace the last field in (each line of) a CSV file with a new string

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I created a script that extracts data from a database and loads it to a csv file. I am using SunOS hstz1454 5.10 system.

Data looks like this below:

```
124,Y,Y,Y,Y,S
125,Y,Y,Y,Y,B
126,Y,N,N,N,B
140,Y,Y,N,N,F
```

The last field should be replaced according to the following mapping:

```
B = BENIGN
C = CUSTOMER
F = FRAME
P = PPCOS
S = STANDARD
W = W-RED
```

How can I replace the last field from the CSV file and convert it to look as follows?

```
124,Y,Y,Y,Y,STANDARD
125,Y,Y,Y,Y,BENING
126,Y,N,N,N,BENING
140,Y,Y,N,N,FRAME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sed:

```
sed s'/S/STANDARD/g'
sed s'/C/Customer/g'
...
...
```

This simple solution will only work if you don't have other uppercase letters of the same value in the CSV field.

If you need it to be only the last character then add a $ to it so it only looks at the very end of the line.

```
echo "124,Y,Y,Y,Y,S" | sed s'/S$/STANDARD/'

124,Y,Y,Y,Y,STANDARD
```

Comment: This will be the very last character and they will all be uppercase letters

Comment: Then my second suggestion will work

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'[, ]' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$NF;next};$NF=a[$NF]' OFS=, file2 file1
```

where file1 is characters file, file2 is data file.

Answer (score 0):

While don_crissti's solution is very professional, I think there should also be a more beginner-friendly one beside it, since neither of the inner workings of `join` nor (keyed) `sort` are anything I would try to explain to a beginner...

Mine uses arrays and...is therefore **expandable**, should there be any identifier added in the future.

Usage is `scriptname <file>`.

**Safer solution:**
(Original file will not be overwritten; you will find the transformed file as `output.csv`)

```
#!/bin/bash

arr_src=("B" "C" "F" "P" "S" "W")
arr_dst=("BENIGN" "CUSTOMER" "FRAME" "PPCOS" "STANDARD" "W-RED")

ftmp="$1"
fout="output.csv"
workfile=".wrkfil"
cp $ftmp $workfile # make backup!

for ((i=0;i<${#arr_src[@]};i+=1)); do
  sed -i 's/'"${arr_src[i]}"'$/'"${arr_dst[i]}"'/g' $workfile
  # echo && cat $workfile
done
mv $workfile $fout
```

**Shorter (but more hazardous) solution:**
(Original file will be overwritten, so should you intend to add another "letter", absolutely make sure that the array lengths of source and destination are always identical!! Otherwise results will be unpredictable.)

```
#!/bin/bash

arr_src=("B" "C" "F" "P" "S" "W")
arr_dst=("BENIGN" "CUSTOMER" "FRAME" "PPCOS" "STANDARD" "W-RED")

fout="$1"

for ((i=0;i<${#arr_src[@]};i+=1)); do
  sed -i 's/'"${arr_src[i]}"'$/'"${arr_dst[i]}"'/g' $fout
  # echo -e "\nOutput file now: $(cat $fout)"
done
```

Comment: The file can be overwritten.

Comment: OK, I'll add a shorter solution, but I'll keep this one anyway. I hate to use the `sed -i` fix-in-place option on the original file, because if there is anything wrong or misinterpreted, your original data will be messed up.

Comment: I got an error  arr_src= unexpected and its in the beginning where you are setting `arr_src=("B" "C" "F" "P" "S" "W")`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Works fine for me. You MUST have `#!/bin/bash` as first line, as my solution will only work with `bash`, not `sh`. I've just read you're using SunOS...maybe you actually got `csh` or `ksh` instead of `bash`? (This was actually the case with the SPARC workstations I had to fight my way through 15 years ago.) The syntaxes of `csh` and `ksh` differ a lot from `bash`'s one.